# rails s exiting unexpected and I can not figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    84: from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    83: from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    82: from /Users/admin/code/cookieMonster42/Present-list/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    81: from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    80: from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    79: from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    78: from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    77: from /Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load': /Users/admin/code/cookieMonster42/Present-list/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting end (SyntaxError)
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag:...
          ^
/Users/admin/code/cookieMonster42/Present-list/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input
  end
  ^~~
```

Tried to fix and `end` in the code but I could not find it and there should not be a problem though I never touched the file before.
Sorry can anyone tell me what this is about??
I can't figure it out.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: When Ruby complains that there is a `SyntaxError` then Ruby is very likely right. Please copy and paste that file into your question.

Comment: Paste the content of `/Users/admin/code/cookieMonster42/Present-list/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` file around line `62` (±5 lines around.)

Comment: If you have "never touched this file" and the default settings are fine with you. You can always just copy and paste the original over whatever happened to yours [Simple Form Bootstrap Config](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb)

Comment: thanks that was the right spot thank you